# ASP trying to convert out from DB and Multiply the 2 values together

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp-classic

hi I am trying to the following:

The code is written in ASP, the output is from a database. I am trying to multiply the QTY and RATE#2 and display total with each order in the returned data. This relates to the last td's in the output.

```
<td align="center" height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("NLCODE") %></td>
<td align="center" height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("QTY") %></td>
<td align="center" height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("QTYRETD") %></td>
<td align="center" height="30"><%= formatcurrency(rowCrossHire("RATE#1"), 2) %></td>
<td align="center" height="30"><%= need to add "QTY" * "RATE#1" here %></td>
```

Anything else required please let me know
Thanks in advance
David

```
<table>
    <%
        crosshireSQL = "SELECT CONTITEMS.CONTNO, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC#2, CONTITEMS.RATE#1, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC#3, CONTITEMS.ITEMNO, CONTITEMS.NLCODE, CONTITEMS.QTY, CONTITEMS.QTYRETD, CONTITEMS.STATUS, CONTRACTS.ACCTNAME FROM CONTITEMS INNER JOIN CONTRACTS ON CONTRACTS.CONTNO = CONTITEMS.CONTNO WHERE CONTITEMS.NLCODE IN ('4001') AND CONTITEMS.STATUS = 1 ORDER BY CONTITEMS.CONTNO ASC, CONTITEMS.ITEMNO ASC"
        set rowCrossHire = returnRecordSet(crosshireSQL)

        currentContract = ""

        if not rowCrossHire.eof then
            ' cross hires found

            do while not rowCrossHire.eof
                ' loop through cross hires

                if currentContract <> rowCrossHire("CONTNO") then
                    ' new contract
    %>
    <tr class="contract">
        <th colspan="11">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        currentContract = rowCrossHire("CONTNO")
        end if

        sonNo = "Pre SONs"

        sonSQL = "SELECT SONID, SONRevision FROM SONs WHERE SONContractNo LIKE '%" & rowCrossHire("CONTNO") & "%' ORDER BY SONID ASC LIMIT 1"
        set rowSON = returnRecordSetOnline(sonSQL)

        if not rowSON.eof then
            ' son found
            sonRevision = ""

            if cint(rowSON("SONRevision")) > 0 then
                ' son revision found
                sonRevision = chr((cint(rowSON("SONRevision")) + 96))
            end if

            sonNO = "<a href=""http://admin.boilerrentalservices.co.uk/sons/list/view-menu.php?SONID=" & rowSON("SONID") & """ target=""_blank"" title=""View " & rowSON("SONID") & sonRevision & """>" & rowSON("SONID") & sonRevision & "</a>"
        end if

        itemDescription = rowCrossHire("ITEMDESC")

        if trim(rowCrossHire("ITEMDESC#2")) <> "" then
            ' additional description
            itemDescription = itemDescription & ", " & rowCrossHire("ITEMDESC#2")
        end if

        if trim(rowCrossHire("ITEMDESC#3")) <> "" then
            ' additional description
            itemDescription = itemDescription & ", " & rowCrossHire("ITEMDESC#3")
        end if          

    %>
    <tr>
        <td height="30"><a href="/dashboard-fullscreen/individual/contracts/view.asp?Allow=f875eba085941cc78509bd3482dc0294&amp;Contract=<%= rowCrossHire("CONTNO") %>" target="_blank" title="View <%= rowCrossHire("CONTNO") %>"><%= rowCrossHire("CONTNO") %></a></td>
        <td height="30"><%= sonNo %></td>
        <td height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("ACCTNAME") %></td>
        <td height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("ITEMNO") %></td>
        <td height="30"><%= itemDescription %></td>
        <td align="center" height="30"><%= getItemStatus(rowCrossHire("STATUS")) %></td>
        <td align="center" height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("NLCODE") %></td>
        <td align="center" height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("QTY") %></td>
        <td align="center" height="30"><%= rowCrossHire("QTYRETD") %></td>
        <td align="center" height="30"><%= formatcurrency(rowCrossHire("RATE#1"), 2) %></td>
        <td align="center" height="30"><%= need to add "QTY" * "RATE#1" here %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
                rowCrossHire.movenext
            loop
        end if
    %>
    <tr class="contract">
        <th colspan="11">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this asp.Net or asp-classic, they are **entirely different**

Comment: @Liam seems like asp-classic i rettagged to reflect this

Comment: @David Your code it's a mess AND **for god sake think how do you tag your questions**

Comment: ASP Classic, sorry I didn't write the code trying to understand it, I have tried to make a change to it. Yes tagging it was a nightmare but as a newbie to the site surely there is some forgiveness?

Comment: I am here to learn Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to select "QTY" * "RATE#1" as a column in your SQL statement, alias it using "AS columnName", then reference columnName in your output.

In your SQL, use

```
QTY * RATE#1 as TotalColumn
```

Where TotalColumn is the value you want to use in your ASP code.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your reply, can you assit in breaking it down in more detail

Comment: Hi David, see my edit. It's really easy to put this into your SQL and just use the column you alias the value as.

Comment: Hi Tim thank you for your valuable input, I have constructed the below query

SELECT CONTITEMS.CONTNO, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC, CONTQTY * CONTRATE#1 AS TOTAL, ....

Thanks again
D

Comment: Hi all, I have added the following changes to the SQL query: <%
      crosshireSQL = "SELECT CONTITEMS.CONTNO, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC#2, CONTITEMS.RATE#1, CONTITEMS.ITEMDESC#3, CONTITEMS.ITEMNO, CONTITEMS.NLCODE, CONTITEMS.QTY, CONTITEMS.QTYRETD, CONTITEMS.STATUS, CONTRACTS.ACCTNAME, CONTITEMS.RATE#1 * CONTITEMS.QTY AS TOTAL FROM CONTITEMS INNER JOIN CONTRACTS ON CONTRACTS.CONTNO = CONTITEMS.CONTNO WHERE CONTITEMS.NLCODE IN ('4001') AND CONTITEMS.STATUS = 1 ORDER BY CONTITEMS.CONTNO ASC, CONTITEMS.ITEMNO ASC"
      set rowCrossHire = returnRecordSet(crosshireSQL)

Comment: I have also added the output column TOTAL too the table <code><tr>  <td align="center" height="30"><%= TOTAL %></td>                                      
</tr></code> but this does not work currently